# Objective-c: Override a method across all sub-classes

Tags: objective-c, oop, overriding

I want to override the `setTitle` method of `UIViewController` across all the sub-classes of UIViewController? I want to customize the title text color of all the views. How can this be done in Objective-C?
Categories is not the recommended way I suppose...

Comment: Categories would certainly be the fastest and most painless way I think. Why do you think it's not the recommended way? You could also create a custom UIViewController subclass, then apply your default styles to that, and then let all your viewcontrollers inherit from that one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/206613 - this says that using categories to override methods inherited from a class is discouraged.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Then you will have to go with a subclass to do it properly, if you don't want to specify for each single viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already pointed out that categories are not the recommended way to do this - and the concers in Apple's documentation are valid - an easy and reliable way would be to create a subclass of UIViewController, use it as a kind of template, and then let all your other viewcontrollers inherit from that "template class".