# UIImagePickerController in iOS 6 doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having a very strange behavior:

1. in iOS 5 I present `UIImagePickerController` in this way:

`imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;`
`imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;`
`imagePicker.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;`

`[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];`

now in iOS 6 this produce a crash. I resolved the crash by writing a category on `UIImagePickerController`:

```
@implementation UIImagePickerController (NonRotating)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

@end
```

The problem is that now the `UIImagePickerController` doesn't rotate and it's shown up-side. Moreover, when I press the "cancel" button and the picker is dismissed, the app crash again.

1. If I use the `UIImagePickerController` inside a `UIPopoverController`, all works fine (belonging to the fact that the popover doesn't rotate) but when I dismiss the popover **ALL view controller in my app stop responding to rotation events** and this cause that all app is blocked in this orientation. To restore the correct behavior I need to quit the app from the background and open again.

This is the code I'm using to display popover

```
_cameraPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
[_cameraPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:_takeFromCamera.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

This problem drive me crazy !

Comment: `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated in iOS 6. This should not crash your app, but maybe you should try `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What is your picker source type?
Photo library/album or camera roll?

Assuming that you are using Photo Library / Album source, on iPad, you MUST use a popover:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html (look in the overview, point 4)

presenting it fullscreen is not supported.

About the other issue (after dismissing the popOver, the other VC's stops rotating) check that you have a STRONG reference to your popover (strong property).
Paste the code you are using to present the popover.

Comment: I use UIImagePicker controller to take a photo from camera.
I edit my question with code.

Comment: Mmmhh, ok, so you can present it modally or in popOver, it's the same. First thing I would do: try to understand why it's crashing when you present it *without* the category. Do you see anything on the log? What happens if you put an exception breakpoint? Moreover, that category doesn't seem a good solution, the methods you are trying to override in the category are, probably, yet implemented in the original UIImagePickerController. Doing this will give you unexpected behavior. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c

Comment: This is the log when app crashes **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!**

Comment: This shouldn't happen :-) I suspect that something in your app code is causing it. Try to do this: Create a new project, iPad only. Choose the single view template. Then, in the ViewController class add this code and check if the picker appears: 
`- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}`

Comment: I've tried in the same project in another view controller and it's work. Maybe the problem is that I show the picker from a modal view controller in pagesheet style ?

Comment: I don't see any indication in the doc about the presentation style supported by UIImagePickerController. But reading this: "On iPad, if you specify a source type of UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera, you can present the image picker modally (full-screen) or by using a popover. However, Apple recommends that you present the camera interface only full-screen." --> there is a part where it says "modally (full-screen)". It could mean that, if is presented modally, must be fullscreen? I think that you can try to change the presentation style...it's only a line of code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While I don't recommend using the category to override the image picker's default behavior, there is a bug in the implementation that causes the crash mentioned:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
                                 ~~~~
}
```

The return value shouldn't be an orientation mask, it should be an orientation, e.g. UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.