# Can't change UIStatusBarStyle on MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I currently use the iOS 7 mechanism of defining the `(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` selector on `UINavigationController` subclasses to control the appearance of the status bar in modally presented views (returning `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`). With an instance of MFMailComposeViewController, I am unable to affect the appearance of the status bar in any way.

It seems like the issue is that the top view of the `MFMailComposeViewController` (which is a `UINavigationController` subclass) is a `MFMailComposeInternalViewController`, which is private and undocumented and seems like something I shouldn't be messing with. Trying to subclass or create a category of it generates compiler errors. It's `preferredStatusBarStyle` is `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`, where I want it to be `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Other answers have suggested setting the plist value of "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO, but I cannot do this without affecting other portions of my application. Is there any way to change the appearance of this status bar?

Comment: I don't think that you are allowed to mess with the MFMailComposerViewController or the MessageComposerViewController because they are Apple's copyright, or "property" I should say.

Comment: I have the same issue. Ever find a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

`MFMailComposeViewController`, since iOS6, is not actually a real view controller, or rather, it does not hold the true view hierarchy of the mail composition view controller. Instead, it is a proxy for a remote view controller, drawn by a different process entirely, using XPC.

Even if you override or swizzle methods in the `MFMailComposeViewController` class, you will not be able to affect its behavior. This is on purpose by Apple.

More information on remote view controllers and XPC here:
http://oleb.net/blog/2012/10/remote-view-controllers-in-ios-6/

Answer (score 1):

Adding a category to MFMailComposeViewController (instead of MFMailComposeInternalViewController) to provide the preferredStatusBarStyle worked for me and didn't generate any compile errors or warnings.

See this question for the original answer I referenced:

[MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 7 statusbar are black](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945390/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-7-statusbar-are-black)

Comment: Did you also enable UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance? That is a prerequisite for this to work.

Comment: If I enable this param status bar font color becomes black for all controllers in my app.

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

stops to work.

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

also doesn't help.

Comment: This isn't a reliable solution, because categories shouldn't be used to override existing methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/18278

Comment: Is it legal to subclass `MFMailComposeViewController`?