# How do I make MFMailComposeViewController's status bar have white text (LightContent)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my `MFMailComposeViewController` I have everything styled to follow the look and feel of my application, but for whatever reason despite my status bar having white content everywhere in my app, when the `MFMailComposeViewController` opens it turns it black.

Is it possible to change the `MFMailComposeViewController`'s status bar to light content?

Comment: Its probably set the by its Navigation Controller and Nav Bar - poke around n the APIs. You can probably find a way to reference it and set it.

Comment: Maybe this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945390/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-in-ios-7-statusbar-are-black

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}];
```

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication setStatusBarStyle:] is deprecated since iOS 10.0