# How do I create a category in Xcode 6 or higher?

Tags: ios, objective-c, categories, xcode6

I want to create a category on `UIColor` in my app using Xcode 6. But the thing is that in Xcode 6 there is no Objective-C category file template.

Is there any option to create a category in Xcode 6?

Comment: how did you do it before Xcode 6?

Comment: Just type it out in a source file: `@interface UIColor(MyCategory) ... ` etc

Comment: Why not select an answer?? Not doing so wastes time for other users looking for the solution.

Comment: If you are using Swift, then you would create an Extension rather than a Category. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31026358/3681880) for how to do it.

Answer (score 746, accepted):

They didn't forget. They just moved it without telling anyone.

1. Click `File` -> `New` -> `File`
2. Select `Objective-C file` under `Sources` in `iOS` or `Mac OS` respectively and Click Next
3. Now under `File Type:` choose either `Category`, `Protocol`, or `Extension`

PS. Under `File Name:` whatever you type here will be either the `Category`, `Protocol`, or `Extension` Name.

Comment: This is so confusing.

Comment: They just accommodated to adding Swift and hidden everything under Objective-C or I think that they did. I personally don't get why Swift was added, Objective-C is such a beautiful and expressive language once you get to know it... It's Objects on top of C... Perrrfect

Comment: Heh, the description given for `Objective-C File` by XCode 6 is "An Empty Objective-C file.", rather than my description which would be, "one of the old, not at all empty, Objective-C files that you're used to", which threw me off fairly nicely!

Comment: @unmircea Thanks for posting such useful information. To Apple: This is stupid!

Comment: **They didn't forget. They just moved it without telling anyone.** what is typical, considering the crappy level of Apple documentations in general and most frequently the total lack of documentation.

Comment: What are you missing on the Documentation level? It's true they always change things but the documentation is very good, although written in a style that is a little different from what other software companies.

Comment: Thanks! I was stumped on this and could not find where they moved it.

Comment: Stack Exchange should change theirs algorithms to bring these kind of answers to the top !!

Comment: This should be the preferred answer

Comment: @unmircea, I don't remember now, but I did stumble upon public methods not documented too.

Answer (score 78):

To create **CategoryBaseClass+CategoryName.m/.h**:

1. File → New → File... or use **⌘N**.
2. Select **Objective-C File**.

[image]

3. Type in category name, select **File Type: Category**, and then select the base class.

[image]

4. Complete the flow to create the category.

Answer (score 37):

Here's a visual demonstration:

[image: creating a category file]

Answer (score 19):

**Xcode6-Beta5 update**

The interface has now changed and it's possible to add a Category directly from the New > File window.

See [unmircea's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324021/how-do-i-create-category-class-in-xcode-6-beta-1/24324565#25054512).

---

I was surprised myself, and I guess because of Swift they *forgot* about good old Objective-C.

You have two options:

1. Create an Objective-C class with the category name, example `UIView+Powerups`, then manually change the interface to match the one of category. Note that the snippet for the category interface and implementation is still working, so that's extra easy: type `@interface-category` and `@implementation-category`.
2. Import it from Xcode 5! Use this command:

   > ```
   > cp -r /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/Cocoa\ Touch/Objective-C\ category.xctemplate /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/Source/
   > ```

   Close and reopen Xcode 6 and you'll find "Objective-C Category" in the wizard for the new file.

Comment: FYI: if you're on a later beta, just change Xcode-beta.app in the line to Xcode6-betaX.app where X is the beta number.

Comment: **Wrong!** Check out the answer by *unmircea* below for the correct answer - it's not gone, it has just moved..

Answer (score 12):

There is no predefined template to create category in Xcode 6 beta(for time being),they may add this option later. As a work around you can create a `Cocoa Touch Class`(its not proper i know but no other way) named `UIImage+Additions`(ClassName+CategoryName) and override its interface and implementation some thing like

#### UIImage+Additions.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage(Additions)

+(void)testMethod;

@end
```

#### UIImage+Additions.m

```
#import "UIImage+Additions.h"

@implementation UIImage (Additions)

+(void)testMethod
{

}

@end
```

**Edit**
This answer was written before finding a way of creating category in the Xcode 6 beta. Check unmircea's answer for the right way of creating category

Comment: Apple forgot to add Objective-c Category, Objective-c class extension, Objective-c Protocols templates....

Comment: I created a bug report #17627118 if you want to duplicate it.

Comment: No need for the workaround now since final version of XCode 6 has category support built-in.

Comment: @Zorayr It was answered before the final Xcode 6 version and the work around is not wrong also. Don't simply down vote.

Answer (score 6):

Extending [unmircea's fantastic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054512/4475605) re: how to create a custom category to implement a custom `UIColor` palette, you could create a category.

Once you've created your category (in this example, it's a **category** called `ColorPalette` of **class** `UIColor`), you'll have a header and an implementation file.

**UIColor+ColorPalette.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIColor (ColorPalette)

// Your custom colors

+ (UIColor *) customRedButtonColor;
+ (UIColor *) customGreenButtonColor;

@end
```

**UIColor+ColorPalette.m**

```
#import "UIColor+ColorPalette.h"

@implementation UIColor (ColorPalette)

// Button Colors

+ (UIColor *) customRedButtonColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:178.0/255.0 green:25.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

+ (UIColor *) customGreenButtonColor {
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:20.0/255.0 green:158.0/255.0 blue:96.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

To use your custom color palette, just import the header into the class where you'd like to implement your custom colors:

```
#import "UIColor+ColorPalette.h"
```

and call the color as you would a standard color like `redColor`, `greenColor`, or `blueColor`.

[Here's a link to a slightly more in-depth discussion](http://www.hesslerdesign.com/blog/ios/custom-uicolor-extensions-for-ios/) of creating a custom palette.

Additionally, here is [a tool to help you select the custom color values](https://color.adobe.com)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 3):

You could just copy the templates you want from an older version of Xcode, I made a shell script for this:https://github.com/cDigger/AddMissingTemplates

Comment: Although this might be a working solution, it's probably a better idea to use the category support built into Xcode - this way, the templates will always be up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can create "extension" file like NSString+Helper:

```
1: File → New → File... or use ⌘N.

2: Name NSString+Helper (For example)

3: create the file

4: Remove the code from file

5: add 

extension NSString {


}
```

Done. enjoy coding