# Apply global class to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

Now I'm not sure if this is possible in Objective-C but I would expect it should be.

I have multiple images across my storyboard using the following/similar code on `UIImages`

```
cell.followingImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.followingImage.frame.size.width / 2;
cell.followingImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

I want to optimise the code. I know you can apply classes to objects but I have never done this before. Is it possible to apply the class via the storyboard and automatically run that code without referencing and adding it to every controller?

So if a class is attached to the `UIImage` it would just run that code and make the `UIImage` a circle? This is probably really simple...

If I was to subclass a UIimage I'm not sure where to put the above code?

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIImage`, add this code into it, then change the class of the UIImage in the storyboard to your custom UIImage subclass.

Comment: Hi @LordZsolt . When I create a subclass of UIImage where does the code go? Do I create a init method within the subclass?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What your "answer" suggests is that you are using `UIImageView`s in the Storyboard. The best approach would be to create a subclass of `UIImageView`, e.g.:

```
//MyImageView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MyImageView : UIImageView
@end
```

The code to adapt the `cornerRadius` and the `clipsToBounds` should be added to the MyImageView.m:

```
//MyImageView.m
- (id)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.view.frame.width.width / 2
    self.layer.clipsToBounds = true;
    // this line may be only needed in init since the clipsToBounds does not change due to autoLayout.
}
```

After writing that code, you need to set the class attribute of all `UIImageView`s in the Storyboard (all those that should be circular) to `MyImageView` instead of the default `UIImageView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a category of UIImage. Include everything you want in this custom category class like your cornerRadius and your clipToBounds code. Then when you init the images, don't init the images with [UIImage new] but with [customImageCategoryName new[. Now, all these images will, by default, have those two lines of code. The following link will show you how to create a category in Xcode [How do I create a category in Xcode 6 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324021/how-do-i-create-a-category-in-xcode-6)

Comment: Im using a storyboard though

Answer (score 0):

Do place that code in 
`-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` method , `-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` method 
and `init` method.

That way if the imageview is from storyboard the initWithCoder will get called and other methods get called when it is programatically added.

Answer (score 0):

As none of the other answers really worked nor were complete enough I used `User Defined Runtime Attributes` instead.

To avoid the need to write it in code I added

`layer.cornerRadius` with `Number` attribute half the width.

`layer.masksToBounds` with `Bool` attribute as `YES`

Comment: How does this have anything to do with applying a class to `UIImage`? You are modifying the `UIImageView`, not the `UIImage` itself.

Comment: Check out my answer. You can do it simply at one place without changing anything.

Answer (score -1):

Method swizzling is a very good option to achieve this.
Create a UIImageView category class and swizzle initWithCoder: method

```
#import "UIImageView+MethodSwizzling.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>


@implementation UIImageView (MethodSwizzling)
+ (void)load {
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(initWithCoder:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(xxx_initWithCoder:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        // When swizzling a class method, use the following:
        // Class class = object_getClass((id)self);
        // ...
        // Method originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, originalSelector);
        // Method swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(class,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        }
        else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}

#pragma mark - Method Swizzling

- (id)xxx_initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder {
    [self xxx_initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    NSLog(@"xxx_initWithCoder: %@", self);
    return self;
}
```

You don't have to create subclass of UIImageView and do not need to change your object's class everywhere in XIB/Storybord.

[Click here](http://nshipster.com/method-swizzling/) to know about  method swizzling.

Comment: It is just disgusting! Without knowing much about swizzling it removes any possibility to understand the code you write in another class. If you just move function calls around you have no idea what method gets called if you just look at the code of one class. DONT do it!

Comment: lik2302 - What is the problem with method swizzling?