# How to reflect properties of UILabel to another?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

Im trying to customize  `UITableViewController` dynamically. So i have changed many properties of `cell.textLabel`. Now i want to copy these properties to `detailTextLabel` and to one label i have created through code. How it can be done?

```
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
    cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

This is my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.textLabel.text=[_names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.tag=indexPath.row;

        cell.detailTextLabel.text=[_phones objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow.png"] ];
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(380,10,30,50)];
        [cell addSubview:imageView];
        //customize the seperator
        UIView* separatorLineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1000, 1)];/// change size as you need.
        separatorLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];// you can also put image here
        [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLineView];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
        cell.textLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        //here i want to copy the properties
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: can you show ur cellforrowatindextpath method

Comment: Create a method that retrieve theses info and apply it to the other one.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have added the code.

Comment: @Larme In compile time, it might be treated same as normal method? i m not sure

Comment: Don't add subview like that in cells because cells are reused.

Comment: i did't get you, can you show an example

Comment: As per your code, imageView's images is a single image. Is it just for example or you're loading images from web/server?

Comment: it is just an example

Comment: So you're loading images from web/server? If yes, you're doing it synchronously or asynchronously?

Comment: does this answer helps you to get what you want? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30776750

Comment: I have edited my answer, try it.

Comment: Will you explain it a bit more?

Comment: why don't you subclass `UILabel`?

Answer (score 4):

For Swift3

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.188235, blue: 0.313725, alpha: 1)
        textColor = UIColor.white
        font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 26)
        autoresizingMask = .flexibleRightMargin
    }
}
```

Create a subclass of `UILabel` in this way.

```
#import "MyLabel.h"

@implementation MyLabel

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
    self.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
    self.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}

@end
```

And now create an object of this MyLabel and your properties will be set automatically and also just assign this class to your label through storyboard to the label in your cell.

Subclassing is the best way for implementing reusable code.

Or else you can even create an extension of class or even an class method in some class which accepts the `UILabel` and sets the properties but this all are not the best practices. Another problem with extensions is the you can only use `self` but not `super`. This may create problems in future when you have to extend the properties.

I hope I am clear and helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to make all the labels of `UITabelViewCell` to same property

Here just loop through the subViews and check whether the subview is of `UILabel`, If it is of `UILabel` then set the property you want.

**My Code :**

```
- (void)formatTheLabelForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)view;

            lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
            lbl.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            lbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
            lbl.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. I want to know is there any code which does the copying and pasting of tools in XCode editor dynamically.

Comment: I have called your 'formatTheLabelForCell' from 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' but I m having many raws in 'ViewController' around 100 so its taking longer time. Looping through views everytime in creation of cell

Comment: It is not recommended to use this much cell to load simultaneously. Even if you did not use load more, are you showing 100 cells in the screen in a single time ??

Comment: Ya I have. That was a client need.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of configuring cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, it's better if you use custom cell. Add `imageView` & `separatorLineView` in your Storyboard/ Nib itself. This way all cells are generated with these default properties. Also if you need to configure something through code, you can code it in your CustomCell.m file like this:

```
 class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.textLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
    //do other configurations
    }
```

Edit: Downloading images from web may be the reason for taking long time loading cells. Try downloading images asynchronously. You can also use this library: [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Note: I know you want it in Objective C, above code in Swift is just for illustration.

Answer (score 2):

> As for swift, you can do this, it will copy all the attributes you applied to textLabel to detailTextLabel.

```
 cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = cell.textLabel.attributedText
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I don't think that there is a function to copy specific properties of a any UIKit component in iOS SDK. Therefore for you will have to write a custom function for this. Additionally there are some issues with your "cellForRowAtIndexPath" as pointed out by others in comments.

There are different solutions to this.

**Solution 1:**
Write a function in your view controller which take two labels as parameters and copy your desired values.

```
-(void)copyPropertiesFrom:(UILabel*)label1 toLabel:(UILabel*)label2{
    label2.backgroundColor  = label1.backgroundColor;
    label2.textColor        = label1.textColor;
    label2.font             = label1.font;
    label2.autoresizingMask = label1.autoresizingMask;
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath where you want to copy do this

```
[self copyPropertiesFrom:cell.titleLabel toLabel:cell.detailTextLabel];
```

**Solution 2(Recommended):** This is best in my little experience because you can reuse it in other view controllers. There might be a better approach than this.

Create a category of UILabel. Check this link [How do I create a category in Xcode 6 or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324021/how-do-i-create-a-category-in-xcode-6-and-7) and also this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-categories--mobile-10648

Your function within category will look like this.

```
-(void)formatLabelToMyStyle{
    self.backgroundColor    = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
    self.textColor          = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.font               = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
    self.autoresizingMask   = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}
```

You will include header file of category and call this function in your cellForRowAtIndexPath like this

```
[cell.titleLabel formatLabelToMyStyle];
[cell.detailTextLabel formatLabelToMyStyle];
[cell.customTextLabel formatLabelToMyStyle];
```

And as for your cellForRowAtIndexPath, larme mentioned in comments "Don't add subview like that in cells because cells are reused" This will keep adding views to your cell hence causing memory issues, Specially when you have large number of cell which in your case is true.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `Category` for `UILabel` or use a subclass of `UILabel` that should share the same styling.

A `Category` for the `UILabel` could look like:

```
// UILabel+CustomStyle.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UILabel (CustomStyle)
-(void) applyCustomStyle;
@end
```

.m file:

```
// UILabel+CustomStyle.m
#import "UILabel+CustomStyle.h"

@implementation UILabel (CustomStyle)

-(void) applyCustomStyle {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0 green: 0.188235 blue: 0.313725 alpha: 1];
    self.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue" size: 26];
    self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
}

@end
```

Then you can apply the same styling by simply calling:

```
#import "UILabel+CustomStyle.h"
[label applyCustomStyle];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use same label configuration to many places in project. Just subclass as @NikhilManapure said.

OR

If you want to apply same properties to **TableViewCell textLabel** and **detailTextLabel**. You should subclass TableViewCell and override Label properties in drawrect method.

Objective-C

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

        @interface PropertiesCell : UITableViewCell

        @end

        #import "PropertiesCell.h"

        @implementation PropertiesCell

        - (void)awakeFromNib {
            [super awakeFromNib];
            // Initialization code
        }

        - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
            [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

            // Configure the view for the selected state
        }

        - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
            [super drawRect:rect];
            [self cellLabelConfigure:self.textLabel];
            [self cellLabelConfigure:self.detailTextLabel];
        }

        - (void)cellLabelConfigure:(UILabel*) contentLabel {
            contentLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.188235 blue:0.313725 alpha:1];
            contentLabel.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            contentLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:26];
            contentLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        }

        @end
```

Swift

```
 class PropertiesCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        cellLabelsConfigure(contentLabel: self.textLabel)
        cellLabelsConfigure(contentLabel: self.detailTextLabel)
    }

    func cellLabelsConfigure(contentLabel: UILabel?) {
        contentLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.188, blue: 0.313, alpha: 1.0)
        contentLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        contentLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 26.0)
        contentLabel?.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleRightMargin
    }
}
```

In storyboard change cell class name to **PropertiesCell**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create an extension class and use this `copy` method to pass all the properties you want to the new label.

```
@implementation UILabel (Copy)

- (UILabel *)copyProperties {
    UILabel *label = [UILabel new];
    [self copyPropertiesWithLabel:label];
    return label;
}

- (void)copyPropertiesWithLabel:(UILabel *)label {
    label.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor;
    label.textColor = self.textColor;
    label.font = self.font;
    label.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask;
    // Add more properties
}

@end
```

Usage:

```
// cell.textLabel has now all the properties
[theLabelToBeCopied copyPropertiesWithLabel:cell.textLabel];
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift3 version:

```
extension UILabel {

    func copyProperties() -> UILabel {
        var label = UILabel()
        self.copyProperties(with: label)
        return label
    }

    func copyProperties(with label: UILabel) {
        label.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        label.textColor = self.textColor
        label.font = self.font
        label.autoresizingMask = self.autoresizingMask
        // Add more properties
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
theLabelToBeCopied.copyProperties(with: cell.textLabel)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for swift.it will copy  for all attributes (textLabel to detailTextLabel).i think @Nikhil Manapure given exact answer.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.attributedText = cell.textLabel.attributedText
```