# No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector URLEncodeUsingEncoding

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i am new to ios and objected C.

I am trying to encode a url, bit i am getting the error

> /Users/zupportdesk/Desktop/MyIOSApps/ZDticketSystem/ZDticketSystem/ViewController.m:313:52:
>   No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector
>   'URLEncodeUsingEncoding:'

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ApplicationEnvironmentURL.h"
#import "AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h"
#import "HHAlertView/HHAlertView.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"


@interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    ApplicationEnvironmentURL *applicationEnvironment;
    NSString *BASEURL;
    NSString *global_profileId;
    AppDelegate *delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *password;
@end

@implementation ViewController
--- defaults methods here

- (void)setupProfileidURL:(NSString *)profileToken {
    NSString *encoded_profileToken = [profileToken URLEncodeUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *user_login_url = [applicationEnvironment get_user_api_url];
    BASEURL = [[user_login_url stringByAppendingString:@"Account/GetProfileDetails?profileToken="] stringByAppendingString:encoded_profileToken];
    NSLog(@"Base URL: %@", BASEURL);
}
```

I am calling the method like this
`[self setupProfileidURL:profileToken];`

**View Holder header file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tv_username;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tv_password;

@end
```

I want to implement this [https://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios](http://This%20url%20encoding) . can some one help me with this url encoding.

Comment: You have to create a category for `NSString` that implement `-URLEncodeUsingEncoding:` and import that category where you need it. See there on how to create a category: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24324021/how-do-i-create-a-category-in-xcode-6-and-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this message

> No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector
>   'URLEncodeUsingEncoding:'

because `URLEncodeUsingEncoding` is a method which is defined in a Category and you are not using that category in your class thats why you are getting this message.

Also `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` is deprecated from iOS so in place of it you can use `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`

Below is an example of of your function

```
- (void)setupProfileidURL:(NSString *)profileToken {
    NSString *encoded_profileToken = [profileToken stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
    NSString *user_login_url = [applicationEnvironment get_user_api_url];
    BASEURL = [[user_login_url stringByAppendingString:@"Account/GetProfileDetails?profileToken="] stringByAppendingString:encoded_profileToken];
    NSLog(@"Base URL: %@", BASEURL);
}
```

Also as per the @Larme comment you can create a category and use it in your application by importing it.