# Top bar color when keyboard is dismissed during search

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have light top bar colors in my app, because the navigation bar is dark brown:

[image: Without search]

When I tap search (Keresés here), the following code sets the top bar color to dark content:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
}
```

So it looks like this:

[image: During search]

But when I type something into the field, then scroll the results list, the keyboard dismisses and the top bar is reverted to white. How can I prevent this?

[image: Keyboard dismissed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 7, the status bar style is, by default, determined by the return value of the `UIViewController` method `-preferredStatusBarStyle`. The default implementation of this method returns `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`.

Setting the info.plist key `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to the value of `NO` returns to the pre-iOS 7 style of taking the status bar appearance from the shared `UIApplication` object

To fix this you have two options:

1) Implement the `-preferredStatusBarStyle` method in all your view controllers that want the status bar style to be non-default

2) Add the key "View controller-based status bar appearance" (`UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`) to your info.plist file and set its value to `NO`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The right way is definitely this one. Your instructions were clear, but unfortunately they don't work for me. If I set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES`, `-preferredStatusBarStyle` gets called but this happens only when I tap Search. The view controllers don't ask this method when they are created. `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` also does not help. If I set `NO`, then `-preferredStatusBarStyle` is not called at all.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19513714/511878

Summary: `UINavigationController` does not forward `-preferredStatusBarStyle` to it's children.