# How to change PreferredStatusBarStyle programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios7, statusbar, uistatusbar

I'd like to change the color of status bar from white to black by press button, **programmatically** only in a single-ViewController

This is the code:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    NSLog(@"PreferredStatusBarStyle");
    if(nav_bar.alpha==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"->UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque");
        return UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"->UIStatusBarStyleLightContent");
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    }}
```

then When I press a button action is:

```
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

**But** this doesn't work!

When I press the button log write the correct status according to navbar.alpha, but statusbar text color remain UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque like when view appear.

Answer (score 12):

`setStatusBarStyle:animated:` has been deprecated. In iOS9 you can achieve the same thing using `preferredStatusBarStyle` and `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`.

In your View Controller:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    if (condition) {
        return .LightContent
    }

    return .Default
}
```

And then when your condition changes:

```
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Answer (score 7):

On Swift 4:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Hope it helps anybody else to find this post.

Comment: Don't forget to call setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()

Comment: yes but how would you change it live

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do, is to call the -setStatusBarStyle:animated: method thru the shared application, like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

you can use it without the animated parameter as well. keep in mind that UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque is deprecated in iOS 7, documentation says you wanna use UIStatusBarStyleLightContent instead

edit:
sorry, if u wanna use preferredStatusBarStyle, take a look at this [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-doesnt-to-get-called)

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];

Comment: This has been deprecated in iOS 9. Other solutions?

Comment: @Arcrammer I've answered above

Comment: have to call [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];

then

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
NSLog(@"PreferredStatusBarStyle");
if(nav_bar.alpha==1)
{
    }