# UIStatusBarStyle not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, uistatusbar, xcode6

I'm trying to change the Status Bar color in my Swift app to white, but am hitting a brick wall. I have 3 ViewControllers that are each embedded in a NavigationController (could that be the issue? I've already tried to place the code in the NavigationController class.) I've tried both of the following pieces of code in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions of my AppDelegate.swift file but neither worked.

```
application.statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

and

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

All that the Docs have to say about it is that UIBarButtonStyle is an Int and gave me this enum snippet which didn't help me at all with implimentation.

```
enum UIStatusBarStyle : Int {
    case Default
    case LightContent
    case BlackOpaque
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You have two options.

If you want to continue manually setting the style of the status bar, continue doing what you're doing, but you'll need to add the following key to your info.plist file with a value of `NO`.

> View controller-based status bar appearance

Or, if you want to continue to use view controller based status bar appearance, instead of setting the application's statusBarStyle, override the `preferredStatusBarStyle` property in each view controller for which you'd like to specify a status bar style.

**Swift 3**

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

**Swift 2**

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code... but I only get the white status bar in first screen.. I am not getting the status bar for the rest of the screens :(.. any help?

Comment: You have to set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" setting in your plist to YES.

Comment: That's only if you _want_ to use a view controller based status bar appearance.

Comment: in iOS 10 (Swift 3.0) its no longer method but property. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862208/preferredstatusbarstyle-removed-in-swift-3

Comment: just for one screen

Answer (score 144):

> **Swift 3.0**

in AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO
```

> **Swift 2.2**

in AppDelegate.swift didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
```

Info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO
```

Comment: sorry, this might be the simplest answer, but it's definitely not the BEST: because it just sets this one style to all and any viewControllers in the app. The behaviour has been introduced to enable finer control and apply different settings based on different view controllers (e.g. mixing light and dark contents).

Comment: It's bizarre - not what the Apple docs say, but it works. Tried a bunch of other ways, including have a UIViewController based status bar, none of them worked.

Answer (score 37):

You have to set the:

`navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .black`

and the text will appear in white

Comment: Thanks! 

There was nothing helped even this 

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

this really helps:

navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .BlackTranslucent
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = true

Comment: Thank! You saved my day. However, BlackTranslucent is deprecated. Hence, I used navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = .Black

Comment: It's perfectly working with `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }`. You just have to write this line in `viewDidLoad` for wrok well. Make sure keep `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` with this solution.

Comment: seems like an overkill... just tried it and worked like this in Info.plist file:
1. Status bar style -> UIStatusBarStyleLightContent
2. View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO

Comment: Making this change made my back button disappear.

Answer (score 21):

For iOS9.x and Xcode7, just put this inside `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .Black

}
```

This will automatically turn your status bar's style to `.Lightcontent` for all the view controllers inside a UINavigationController.

(Also, delete `View controller-based status bar appearance` from Info.plist to suppress the warnings you're probably seeing too!)

Comment: thank you. There seems to be a serious bug in iOS9. This was the only way I could turn the status bar in the initial VC white. I tried everything. I'll file an radar.

Comment: preferredStatusBarStyle returning UIStatusBarStyleDefault but not updating lightcontent to darkcontent for specific viewcontroller . After self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle=UIBarStyleDefault; in viewWillAppear worked for me . Hope this comment will help others.

Comment: Note that the UIStatusBarStyle has been changed to ".black" (lowercase B) in Swift 3

Answer (score 16):

In Swift 3, status bar style has changed to a computed property in UIViewController that you can override like this:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
   return .lightContent //or default
}
```

Answer (score 13):

On iOS 9 the following (setStatusBarStyle) is deprecated and you will get a warning if you go that way.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)
```

If you want all statusBars changed in a single shot try adding the following to your Info.plist. This will also make your launch-screen status bar white. While the code above won't.

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```

Comment: The .plist approach is correct, but setStatusBarStyle() is not necessary.

'setStatusBarStyle(_:animated:)' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]

Comment: @BillChan thanks for commenting but please read the answer gain. I already explained 'setStatusBarStyle' was deprecated. You should use preferredStatusBarStyle if you want one or another viewControllers changed. The plist approach is for who wants all viewControllers changed in a single shot. There is no right or wrong here. Just a matter of what you need  to achieve.

Comment: UIStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent (in .plist) helped my app launch with white status bar text ... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 11):

for me all above dind't work until i add:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black;
```

so:

1. Set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in `.plist`
2. In `viewDidLoad` call `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate();`
3. Override preferredStatusBarStyle 

   `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
           return .lightContent 
       }`
4. In overrided method i set also the `navigationBar.barStyle` so final

    for **light** content: 
   `override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
           self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black;//or default
           return .lightContent //or default
       }`

    and for **black** content use default

The source from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768797/2050181) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19513714/2050181).

and if this doesn't work you can try add a `UINavigationController` `extension`:

```
extension UINavigationController
{
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if let lastVC = self.viewControllers.last
        {
            return lastVC.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }

        return .default
    }
}
```

Comment: No comment for navigation bar style... but in Swift 3, Xcode 8 - this was the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: The only drawback I've noticed is that with all those steps it changes but without animation

Answer (score 5):

Strange, using Swift 3.1 & XC8.2.1, but all of the above didn't work.

What I did, is just

```
extension UINavigationController
{
    override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        get {
            return .lightContent
        }
    }
}
```

No Plist, no other stuff.
HTH

Comment: Works for Swift 4.2 too.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3.0 you can override a getter in ViewController for View controller-based status bar appearance:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    get { return .lightContent }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't edit your Info.plist. Add this to your ViewController.swift:

```
override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. Add to info.plist `View controller-based status bar appearance -> NO`

Step 2. Add code in method where you need to change status bar color:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent //(or .default)
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Key line of code: `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`