# Change the style of the UISearchController views?

Tags: swift, swift3, tvos

### Question:

How do I change the color/theme/style of the `UISearchController` in `tvOS`?

( Would appear I need to set [UIStatusBarStyle](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistatusbarstyle) some way, since the [preferredStatusBarStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862208/preferredstatusbarstyle-removed-in-swift-3) override does not exist in `tvOS` for `UISearchController`)

### Description:

Method called in my `AppDelegate` to programmatically create a `searchNavigationController` with on top a `UISearchController` and on bottom my custom `UITableViewController` called "`searchResultsController`" (`SearchViewController`)

```
func configueSearchController() -> UIViewController {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil)
    guard let searchResultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SearchViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchViewController else {
        fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultViewController from the storyboard.")
    }

    /*
     Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
     use to display search results.
     */

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. Gastric Bypass)", comment: "")

    // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
    let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
    searchContainer.title = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")

    // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
    let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
    return searchNavigationController

}
```

**Image of the visual representation of the above method:**

[image: UISearchViewController]

### What I've tried:

I've attempted to change the style via different approaches and none of them gave the desired outcome.

This has no effect on the searchBar:

```
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal //or .prominent or .default
```

This only makes the searchBar (actual input area black.. with black text..):

```
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .black
```

This only makes the whole background view of the UISearchController black. Everything is black and thus the keyboard can not be seen.

```
searchController.view.backgroundColor = .black
```

The ideal solution would be a theme change from the standard `.default` to something `.dark`. Because not only does the background color have to change but the borders and text colors must too.

**Attempted to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862208/preferredstatusbarstyle-removed-in-swift-3):**

```
//UISearchController
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

However, this override does not seem to exist for tvOS. Any reason why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around to this problem, however I don't really understand why they don't keep the same system as for iOS. Anyway, the main things to do to change the SearchBar style to black is to set the `keyboardAppearance` to dark, the `searchController`'s view's background color and to set the `searchBar`'s background color to white.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    guard let win = window else {
        return true
    }



    if let tabController = win.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        tabController.viewControllers?.append(configueSearchController())
    }

    win.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    win.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}   
func configueSearchController() -> UIViewController {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Search", bundle: nil)
    guard let searchResultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SearchViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchViewController else {
        fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultViewController from the storyboard.")
    }

    /*
     Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
     use to display search results.
     */

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. Gastric Bypass)", comment: "")
    searchController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.dark
    searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    //searchResultsController.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
    let searchContainer: UISearchContainerViewController = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)

    // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
    let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
    searchNavigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    searchNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
    searchNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Search"
    return searchNavigationController

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For all those wanting to achieve this on tvOS with a TabBarController and storyboard, what I did was add a container view to my view controller and added the tab bar controller as a child.

```
class SearchController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let searchController = UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        searchController.view.frame = containerView.bounds        

        let searchContainer: UISearchContainerViewController = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)

        // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
        let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
        searchNavigationController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        searchNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .black
        searchNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Search"

        containerView.addSubview(searchNavigationController.view)
        searchNavigationController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on tvOS, but here's what I've found.
I started with the [UIKit Catalog: Creating and Customizing UIKit Controls](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UICatalogFortvOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016433) example code from Apple. The first thing that I noticed is that the code you supplied above instantiates the `searchResultsController` as a `SearchViewController`, whereas Apple's example code instantiates the `searchResultsController` as a `SearchResultsViewController`. I assume you meant to do this.

After playing around with the example code, I was able to make very limited style changes. Here is a screenshot of the closest I have come to what it seems you are trying to achieve.

[image]

And here is the code that affected that change.

```
func packagedSearchController() -> UIViewController {
    // Load a `SearchResultsViewController` from its storyboard.
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ViewControllerSamples", bundle: nil)
    guard let searchResultsController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: SearchResultsViewController.storyboardIdentifier) as? SearchResultsViewController else {
        fatalError("Unable to instatiate a SearchResultsViewController from the storyboard.")
    }

    /*
        Create a UISearchController, passing the `searchResultsController` to
        use to display search results.
    */
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("Enter keyword (e.g. iceland)", comment: "")

    //** This is the part you are interested in **//
    searchResultsController.view.backgroundColor = .black
    searchController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.25, blue: 0.25, alpha: 1.0)
    searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = .white

    // Contain the `UISearchController` in a `UISearchContainerViewController`.
    let searchContainer = UISearchContainerViewController(searchController: searchController)
    searchContainer.title = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")

    // Finally contain the `UISearchContainerViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.
    let searchNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: searchContainer)
    return searchNavigationController
}
```

Unfortunately, I was unable to set the SearchController's view to .black without loosing the keyboard in the darkness. I looked and looked for a solution to the disappearing keyboard problem thinking that there must be a way to style the keyboard, or at least modify the selection state, all to no avail. My disappointment culminated in this statement from the [App Programming Guide for tvOS: Designing the Keyboard Experience](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/CreatingaGreatTextInputExperience.html);

> An inline keyboard displays all of the possible inputs on a single line. Use UISearchController to create a keyboard that can be fully integrated with third-party content. However, there are very few customization options when you use UISearchController. You can not access the text field itself, customize the traits, or add input accessories.

I suspect that if you could get a reference to that keyboard, you may be able to affect some change. That being said, I have not been able to find a real solution to date. Maybe you could attach a custom inputAccessoryViewController to the SearchController and effect a change that way?

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.