# Setting statusbarStyle (deprecated in iOS 9.0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Just downloaded the new xCode 10.0 and saw that the old statusBarStyle has been deprecated since iOS 9.0.

**Warning:** `Setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: Use -[UIViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]`

**Deprecated code:**
`UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default`

I tried using `self.preferredStatusBarStyle`, but found out the property is only a getter. So anyone knows how to set the `statusBarStyle`?

### Edit

I want to change the statusBarStyle inside a function, where a user can switch between different themes. For example:

```
func changeStatusBar(toDarkMode: Bool) {
    if toDarkMode {
        // Set to light statusBarStyle
    } else { 
        // Set to default
    }
}
```

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set your darkMode variable using the same code you have now, then use it in the computed variable that the system is expecting:

```
var darkMode = false
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return darkMode ? .default : .lightContent
}
```

Depending on the context you may need to force a refresh of the screen for it to take effect.  You would do that with the following call:

```
setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Comment: It seems good, but the statusBarStyle doesn't get updated even if I use this line of code. I used a didSet closure in the darkMode boolean, that updates the statusBarAppearance. It gets called whenever I change the bool value. But the statusBarStyle doesn't change. Do you have any clue on what it could be?

Comment: Are you setting this in the root viewController?  See this discussion in Apple's docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621433-childforstatusbarstyle

Comment: @paulking I am using same But In iPHOne XS, XR and  XS max  default launch(splash) screen Not Showing light content of status bar.

Comment: @BalKrishanYadav, launch/splash screens do not execute any code, so in this case you would need to set the "Status Bar Style" for the app target under General/Deployment Info.

Comment: as @paulking suggested setting it in the rootviewcontroller does the trick.

Comment: If you use a Navigation Controller, which a lot of apps do, use the extension mentioned in the answer by CryingHippo or else this won't work.

Answer (score 46):

Add `View controller-based status bar appearance NO` in `Info.plist`

And select Light in Status Bar Style in Deployment Info

[image]

Comment: That's how you set up for the first time. If you want to switch during the application run, between dark and light. That was the question

Comment: but this is how I managed to set it up because other solutions where not working for me

Comment: No it's not the only way. Scroll up to @MdRashedPervez answer and you'll see another way how to change the status bar for different viewControllers.

Comment: @JacobAhlberg Not sure why but this is the only way for me to make the status bar light colour. I tried MdRashedPervez solution but it didn't work for me

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: @JacobAhlberg yes

Comment: I just tried out @CryingHippos answer and it worked smooth. I had to use extension of `UINavigationController` and just returned the style I wanted. Check it out!

Answer (score 27):

In **swift4**, You can use this block of code below `viewDidLoad()` in your `ViewController`-

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Comment: I'm actually switching between two different themes (light and dark) so I have to change the statusBarStyle inside a function. You have any clue on how?

Comment: set a tag for ur themes inside your function for those two different theme. E.g. for theme1 set tag1 then if it gets tag 1 then it will show status bar light. Same for others.

Comment: I'm actually using a mapView which goes behind the statusBar and whenever a user changes the mapType from default to satellite I have to change the statusBar so it doesn't blend into the mapView. So I can't really set a tag on that... Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Md Rashed Pervez I added your code from above, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @icekomo did you put the code below the viewDidLoad() in your ViewController

Comment: @MD Rashed Pervez I did. I also read that having a Nav Controller might make a difference. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @icekomo Please go through this tutorial -  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jz_pT0MELxE

Comment: @MD Rashed Pervez, thanks for the video. I followed the steps but autocomplete doesn't give me the option for that function he is using. Did something change from the time the video was posted until now?

Comment: From what I have read, this chagned, and it is no longer a func.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862208/preferredstatusbarstyle-removed-in-swift-3

Comment: Can you explain why it should be placed below viewDidLoad() please? @md-rashed-pervez

Answer (score 13):

If you use UINavigationController you also may want to use following code :

```
extension UINavigationController {
   open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
   }
}
```

Reason is `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` doesn't call childs `preferredStatusBarStyle`

Comment: Where would I put this if I used the embed Navigation Controller under the Editor menu?

Answer (score 5):

None of the other suggestions worked for me. I ended up getting it to work by:

1. Setting:

   ```
   override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
       return .lightContent
   }
   ```
2. Calling:

   ```
   setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
   ```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was as this:
making an extension from the navigation controller:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        if let topViewController = presentedViewController{
            return topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }
        if let topViewController = viewControllers.last {
            return topViewController.preferredStatusBarStyle
        }

        return .default
    }
}
```

and if you have a viewController that will have another style than the style of the app , you can make this

```
var barStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
    return barStyle
}
```

lets say that you app status style is `.default` and you want this screen to be `.lightContent`
so barStyle will take the `.lightContent` as its default value, this will change the status bar style to lightContent, and then make sure when `viewWillDisappear` change the barStyle again to the app status bar style which in our case is `.default` .

***this is works for me***

Comment: Do not attempt to override methods in an extension. It is undefined behavior and [the documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) states that you should not do it.