# How to change status bar style - iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, ios12

I need to update status bar style on every view controller based on the background color (what `UINavigationController` is doing automatically).

Have tried all the options described on stackoverflow (`View controller-based status bar appearance` in `info.plist` set to **YES**), but none worked for me.

I am using Xcode 10 beta 6 and Swift 4.2, targeting iOS 12.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting statusbarStyle (deprecated in iOS 9.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693665/setting-statusbarstyle-deprecated-in-ios-9-0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` in the `info.plist` and override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in each view controller like so:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

And call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in your view controller (in `viewDidLoad()` for example).

Comment: You are right! But that's being deprecated since iOS 9. But did I miss something? I set the value to info.plist. Then added this line to viewDidLoad() of particular view controller. No visible changes.

Comment: @TomášPánik are you calling `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`?

Comment: sure. xcode telling me "setter for 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: use `-[UIViewController prefferedStatusBarStyle]`". do you know how to it? note that I am getring another error "property does not override any property from it's superclass" for some reason, while using `override var prefferedStatusBarStyle ...`

Comment: error "method does not override any method from its superclass"

Comment: @TomášPánik are you using it in a UIViewController?

Comment: ofc. `class blabla: UIViewController`

Comment: I can pull this project to my github if you are curious whats wrong with it just like me :D

Comment: not working with override at all. I am pulling to github, give me 2 minutes

Comment: edit: works now on both projects; I had to miss something, I believe I've tried this as well -.-

Comment: note: this method works with plist boolean set to YES

Comment: you can search the other answers regarding this :) thanks a lot I don't know what was wrong when I was trying all the answers from stackoverflow, but now it works :)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: If using a modally presented view controller you may need to set `myViewController.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` on the view controller to be presented modally. I could not get this answer to work unless I did this. The `info.plist` key was set to `yes`.

Answer (score 34):

**Swift 4+, iOS 12+**

`View controller-based status bar appearance` now needs to be set to `YES` in `info.plist` since UIKit no longer wants us to edit status bar style through `UIApplication.shared`—status bar style is now view-controller based.

Then if you want the change to be applied at app level, simply override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in the appropriate container view controller (ideally the root)...

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

...and this will propagate to all view controllers underneath it. And if you want to edit status bar style per view controller, apply this override per view controller.

If status bar style ever changes during runtime, then you need to call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` (from anywhere in the container/root view controller or that specific view controller), otherwise it isn't needed.

Comment: This! All other answers regarding setting `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` **WILL NOT WORK**.

Comment: I use custom transitions between View Controllers. Since iOS 12 animation of the status bar is broken, I used a smooth transition from light to default and vice-versa. In iOS 12 status bar blinks for short time before a transition. Do you know what has been changed?

Comment: And, if the UIApplication's rootViewController is a tabbarvc or navigationvc(container view controller), then this vc will take over the control, you can override `childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle` method and return the controller which you want to take over the control. For example, the tabbar returns `selectedViewController`(navigationvc), and the navigationvc returns its `topViewController`.

Answer (score 15):

If you have `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `info.plist` set to **YES** and your view controller is embedded into `UINavigationController`, then your navigation controller will be responsible for updating bar style (through `navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle`) and `preferredStatusBarStyle` property will be ignored

Answer (score 11):

I have Xcode 10.2 and found as you did that setting the View controller-based status bar appearance in info.plist to "YES" will not change the status bar style at all. 
However, I did find that changing two keys in the info.plist file will do all the work of changing the status bar to light or dark without any additional coding. 
 
**Here's what I did to fix it for myself**
When hovering over the top line "Information Property List" from the info.plist file, a small round "+" button will appear. Click this button and scroll through the items until you find the following keys.
**View controller-based status bar appearance** [set this value to]   **NO** 
 **Status bar style**  [set this value to] **UIStatusBarStyleLightContent** 
**NOTE:** *The UIStatusBarStyleLightContent is not found as a selectable item in the value list and must be typed into the value box.*
[image: info.plist]

I hope this helps you or anyone else looking for an answer to this question.

Comment: But will UIStatusBarStyleLightContent change the statusbar color on every ViewController based on the content?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't see that part in the question LOL, Looks like I need to pay more attention to the questions here. No, it does not change them based on content. It will just change them for the whole project.                                                              Thanks for pointing that out!.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wrapped in a nav controller, you're going to need this:

```
final class LightNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

I applied scroll view also in the same screen, by this code was able to resolve status bar issue.

Comment: This code doesn't do anything about changing status bar style!