# How to set launch screen status bar color to white?

Tags: ios, swift, uistatusbar

My application's launch screen has a dark background color, so I'd like to set the status bar color to white while it's showing.

This differs from the question asked in [How to change status bar style - iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238121/how-to-change-status-bar-style-ios-12). That solution works for me for view controllers **once the application is running** but I can't find a way to apply it to the launch screen.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For that you have to change **Status Bar Style** to **Light** from "General" tab under project target.

[image: An image showing how to do the instructions.]

#### How to set in the entire app

Above only change the status bar color of launch screen to white & rest of controller have black color. If you wanted to change the entire project status bar color to white then add below too :

**On you project plist file:**

1. Status bar style: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`
2. View controller-based status bar appearance: `NO`
3. Status bar is initially hidden: `NO`

Comment: That worked but shouldn't it be the other way around? Light content -> black status bar

Comment: @DenisBarzanov Content refers to the content of the status bar, this had me confused for a long time.

Comment: This is not working for me, any idea what else could be messing with it?