# How to change status bar color in launch screen. Swift

Tags: swift, uikit, interface-builder, statusbar, launch-screen

Status bar color in my launch screen doesn't change. On other viewController status bar color changes. View controller-based status bar appearance installed on the NO. How can I fix it?

Comment: this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939953/how-to-set-launch-screen-status-bar-color-to-white

Comment: I tried this. But it doesn't work for me