# Status Bar Text Color on iPhone XR is different

Tags: ios, objective-c, statusbar

Already checked answers from StackOverflow to change status bar color for the whole app is to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` in info.plist to `NO` and `Status bar style` to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

Well it did change from iPhone XS and lower, but iPhone XR and iPhone XS Max were not, Still solid black. I tried to find in code if there is a code that called `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` but I dont see it anywhere. My current fix now is to put this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 12, setting `NO` at `View controller-based status bar appearance` in `Info.plist` won't work anymore; you must set it to `YES`. Your workaround is the recommended way to do so.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443917/188331

Comment: Thank you! I think yes, this is the root cause.