# XR status bar text remains black, but not iPhone 8 or iPad

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, statusbar, iphone-xr

Using the techniques out there in googleland, I have set my iOS statusbar text to white. This works fine except for iPhone XR, which sets the text black.

The techniques I find for dealing with this are all Swift and Objective C related. What is the technique for Xamarin.Forms?

In plist I have

- Status bar style = White
- View controller-based status bar appearance = No

Based on this related question, [Status Bar Text Color on iPhone XR is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282658/status-bar-text-color-on-iphone-xr-is-different), I tried

- View controller-based status bar appearance = Yes

But that turns all iOS devices status bar to black, including XR. Then it talks about some Swift code for which I don't know the analog in Xamarin.

Based on this related question,
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89840/change-status-bar-color-on-ios

It is close but it changes the bar's background color. I can't find any property on the statusBar object that talks about text color.

Based on this related question,
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17922/navigationpage-statusbar-color

Using SetStatusBarStyle doesn't affect XR either.

Note: I'm not using NavigationPage

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. It seems like you will need to use a custom renderer for this. In the ViewController, you will override the PreferredStatusBarStyle function to any of the three enums [shown here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistatusbarstyle) as follows:

```
public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle()
{
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
}
```

Comment: Sammer, in Xamarin.Forms iOS project we have AppDelegate.cs and Main.cs. Neither have that override and I don't know what a ViewController is in this context.

Comment: Hey John, as I mentioned, you have to create a Custom Renderer. Can you also share what other devices & iOS versions are you seeing this issue.

Comment: Sure, so I have physical iPad 5th gen, iPhone 8 and iPhone XR all running 12.2. Then I have all the simulators available to Visual Studio 2017 connected to MacBook Pro which runs Mojave. The XR real and sim are the ones with the issue. I have't tried all the other simulators.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2 solution with NavigationController**

**First Step:**

Open your info.plist and insert a new key named **"View controller-based status bar appearance"** or **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** to **YES** to let each VC use their own status property.

**Second Step**

In each VC, override the preferredStatusBarStyle property like this :

`override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent //.default for black style
}`

**Last step**

Override the preferredStatusBarStyle property in your custom NavigationController class :

`class NavigationController : UINavigationController {

override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {

```
if let topVC = viewControllers.last {
    //return the status property of each VC, look at step 2
    return topVC.preferredStatusBarStyle  
}

return .default
```

}
`

Comment: Thank you Habin, but I'm not using Swift. I asked about Xamarin.Forms.

Answer (score 0):

I know we should not use `UIStatusBarStyle` now. But it does work on iOS 12.2 on my XR simulator. I added the keys in my info.plist:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
```

The status bar's text changes to the white:
[image]

Using code to change the color also works fine:

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
```

You can utilize it to adjust the status bar style dynamically.

However, creating a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) for your specified page is another option. Firstly, set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to true in the info.plist.

Then the page renderer could be like:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MainPage), typeof(CustomPageRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class CustomPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override UIStatusBarStyle PreferredStatusBarStyle()
        {
            return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent;
        }
    }
}
```

`MainPage` is a content page class on Forms. And I set it to the App's `MainPage`.