# What to use instead UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

Tell me, please, is there a way to change the color of the status bar text for the Navigation Bar?

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

**deprecated in iOS 13.0**

What to use instead `UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change status bar style - iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238121/how-to-change-status-bar-style-ios-12)

Comment: As I wrote above, the method suggested in the answer is deprecated in iOS 13. What can I use instead?

Comment: The answers that I linked to suggest using `Info.plist` and overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle`. I'm not seeing any evidence that they are deprecated, whereas the method that you listed in your question was deprecated in iOS 9.0 and MacCatalyst 13.0.

Comment: Thanks, but is not work for me(
I use `View controller-based status bar appearance`. (try `YES`. and `NO`, it's not change result).

And I use 
`override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theme") == nil ? "light" : UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "theme")) == "dark" ? .lightContent : .darkContent
    }
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In info.plist `View controller-based status bar appearance: YES`

In `class MyTabBarController : UITabBarController` (he set my rootViewControllers)

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
 return (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "theme") == nil ? "light" : UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "theme")) == "dark" ? .lightContent : .darkContent
 }

 override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
 return nil
 }
```