# How do I change the statusBarStyle using the statusBarManager in iOS 13.0+

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13

I am trying to change the status bar style in my iOS 13.0 app but when I use the code;

```
   UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

I get the warning in Xcode;

```
   'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene instead
```

The problem is that the property `statusBarManager?.statusBarStyle` is a get only property so how can I change the status bar style programmatically?

Comment: you can find your solution using below the link: [statusbarstyle change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238121/how-to-change-status-bar-style-ios-12)

Comment: This should be done at the view controller

Comment: @VaibhavKhatri I have tried all of those solutions and none of them work. Its very confusing as well because some contributors say set YES and some say set NO to the plist Key.

Comment: @LeoDabus The only way it will work is if I use ```UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContext``` or ```UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default``` programmatically with the Info.plist key value set to NO.

Answer (score 0):

Set View controller-based status bar appearance key value in info.plist to NO and programmatically set UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle to either .lightContent or .default.

Comment: Not sure how telling the guy to do the same thing as what he is doing will get rid of the warning.