# iOS 7 : How to change the status bar text color as white in one view controller and black in second view controller?

Tags: iphone, ios7, statusbar

I need to change the color of status bar text in first view controller to white and in the second view controller it should  change to black. Tried with View controller-based status bar appearance to NO and called

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

But it was not changing. Please suggest me.

Comment: try this code in viewdidload method of desired viewcontroller [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate]; working in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your Plist file and add this property with Bool YES.

Then use

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**Have a look into attached screenshot-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to have view controller based status bar appearance set to YES for `preferredStatusBarStyle` to work. If you're still having issues after that then take a look at this SO question: [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called)