# How to change background color of UIStatusBar when using a UINavigationController in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, statusbar, swrevealviewcontroller

In my project I've integrated the SWRevealViewController, and while I was setting it up I noticed that one of my view controllers - managed by a UINavigationController - had a black status bar even though the background color of the view controller is white. How can I change the Status Bar color back to white? (Either programmatically or in the Interface Builder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If below the status bar is a navigation bar, the status bar style will be adjusted to match the navigation bar style (UINavigationBar.barStyle):

Specifically, if the navigation bar style is `UIBarStyleDefault`, the status bar style will be `UIStatusBarStyleDefault`; if the navigation bar style is `UIBarStyleBlack`, the status bar style will be `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent`.

So in your case as status bar is black,
If you want `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` on a UINavigationController use:

```
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

Also you can refer: [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called/19513714#19513714)

Comment: I think he meant the color of the background under the status bar icons, not the color of status bar icons, example he doesn't want to change the color of battery icon from back to white maybe he want to leave it as black but change the background to blue for example, Thats what I understand from his title and question.