# how to animate status bar style change since iOS 9

Tags: ios

So I used to use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent 
                                            animated:YES];
```

to animate the status bar style change, from dark to light and vice versa

However this method is deprecated since iOS 9.

I do changed to use `preferredStatusBarStyle` following @serenn's answer in [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called)

It indeed can change the status bar style in old fashion, but without animations.

The documentation said:

***If the return value from this method changes, call the setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate method.***

However I have no idea where to call it, I tried put it in viewWillAppear, but no luck.

`preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation` remains as default:`UIStatusBarAnimationFade`

So I am confused. Looking for answers for how to animate as the deprecated method. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18):

OK I have spent two hours searching and trying, figured it out:

First, you have to make sure your child view controller can control the status bar style in the navigation controller by overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` like @serenn's answer in [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called)

In order to have animation, I have to return two different style before and after the view controller appears like below:

```
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    if (!viewAppeared)
        return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
    else
        return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; // your own style
}
```

`viewAppeared` is a BOOL to indicate if the `viewWillAppear` is called:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    viewAppeared = YES;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    viewAppeared = NO;
}
```

So when the view controller does not appear, the status bar style is `UIStatusBarStyleDefault` and will be changed to `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` in `viewWillAppear`.

Then call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` to update the change like below, be noted `animateWithDuration` is a must to have animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}];
```

I used to find out you don't have to call `preferredStatusBarStyle` first like below, `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` will invoke `preferredStatusBarStyle` again:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 animations:^{
    [self preferredStatusBarStyle];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}];
```

Though this solution solve the problem, I don't choose to use it for now. I can have the same result with only one line code but it is now way too many of the code I have to write. The deprecated API does not even trigger a warning right now, so until Apple keeps pushing me to change, I will not use this way. When the time comes I hope there is a good solution then.

I am very confused why Apple deprecated the one-line code (`[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle]...`)that can do all the tricks, but use a more complicated to achieve the same result. Even you want to give more fine-grained control, Apple does not have to deprecated the old one.

But maybe I just didn't find the best one right now. Hope someone could enlight me.