# How to animate changing status bar style?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to change status bar style when presenting a view controller, and change it back when returning from it, this is my code:

**In presented:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
}
```

**In presenting:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
}
```

**My info.plist:**

- View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
- Status bar style = default

The animation seemed quite intrusive, am I able to animate the change?

Comment: You should tried this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405891/how-to-animate-status-bar-style-change-since-ios-9

Comment: @aircraft that solved my problem, you can add a swift version here to let everyone see.

Comment: thanks your advice, and I will do that after some hours. Busy now.

Answer (score -1):

At First you do this:
Open your info.plist and insert a new key named "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO

and change the statusBar colour in whatever viewController.

Like this : UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent

If you want to change colour on changing viewController put like this:

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool)

{
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.Default
```

//this will change the colour when a particular viewController disappear.

}