# Modal View Controller with Different StatusBar Style than the ParentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a view controller with a Light Status Bar Style, and then a user can press a button which modally presents a Game Center Leaderboard. However, I want the modal view controller to have a `.Default` style when the parent view controller has a `.LightContent` style. Is this possible to do? Can the modal view controller have a different style than the parent view controller? If so, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Definitely possible. In each view controller, are you overriding `- preferedStatusBarStyle:`?

Comment: @ajfigueroa Actually since I am presenting a Game Center leaderboard I don't have a view controller for the Game Center Leaderboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think I figured out a good solution to my question. Basically when presenting modally, you have a `completionHandler`. In the `completionHandler` put these lines of code when you are presenting the modal view:

```
self.setStatusBarStyle(.Default)
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

When you are dismissing the modal view:

```
self.setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent)
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

**Make sure not to implement the preferredStatusBarStyle in your View Controller. That method was throwing me off and if you implement the preferredStatusBarStyle method it will override the setStatusBarStyle method and this trick won't work. Basically DO NOT implement preferredStatusBarStyle.**

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. My solution was to override: `GKGameCenterViewController`class
Then I've followed [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032879/4064503): I have added 
`preferredStatusBarStyle()` method into my override view controller and set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in the .plist file.

Comment: Just one question though for some reason when I use your solution the whole apps status bar appearance turns black. How do I have some white status bar colors? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have also put `preferredStatusBarStyle()` into my `BaseViewController` which I use as parrent class to all of my View controllers.

Comment: I have done that, but it is not working when I set the value to NO in the plist, and it works when the value is set to YES in the plist.

Comment: Do you have your views in the `Navigationview`?

Comment: No, I don't have my views embedded in a Navigation View. The views have white status bars if the view controller based status bar appearance is set to yes, but then the Game Center View status bar is white instead of black

Answer (score 2):

This solved it for me:

```
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is based on @Harish's solution. In your specific `UIViewController` (or your own base class) add:

```
var statusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle = .lightContent
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return statusBarStyle
}
```

And call:

```
self.statusBarStyle = .default // or .lightContent
self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

Whenever you want to change status bar style.