# preferredStatusBarStyle never called

Tags: ios, iphone, uistatusbar

My view controller hierarchy is `SWRevealViewController` -> `UINavigationViewController` -> `MyController1`. `MyController1` presents `MyController2` using `self.present`. `MyController2` is not within `UINavigationViewController` and presentation is modal (device is iPhone). In `viewWillAppear` of `MyController2` I call `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()`, but `preferredStatusBarStyle` is never called by the system and status bar appearance remains same (as it was for `MyViewController1`). Am I missing something here?

**EDIT**

`info.plist` has **View controller-based status bar appearance** set to `YES`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called)

Comment: yes, I looked through the whole thread. nothing helped. my controller is not inside `UINavigationController` as i mentioned

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me in my VC...

```
self.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true
```

Comment: It only affects when you use non-full screen modal presenting styles.

Answer (score 4):

in your info.plist

**View controller-based status bar appearance** make it YES

Answer (score 4):

Our issue was a container VC.

So had to tell it to allow the contained (visible) VC to call the shots:

```
final class ContainerVC: UIViewController {
  final var centerVC: UIViewController? // set to an OtherVC elsewhere

  override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
    return centerVC
  }
  override var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
    return centerVC
  }
}

final class OtherVC: UIViewController {
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }
  override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
  }
  override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .slide
  }
}
```