# PreferredStatusBarStyle not called

Tags: ios, swift

Okay I'm losing my mind here. Here is how my code is:

**.plist**

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<true/>
```

**Overrides**

```
extension UINavigationController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }

    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }

    open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
    }
}

extension UITabBarController {
    open override var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return children.first
    }

    open override var childForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return children.first
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

I have went as far as crying for an update:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}
```

I know this has been asked and answered before and I have went through most if not all the answers on the platform and none could help. I don't know what to do anymore. *Please help :(*

***Oh I tried this too***

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

None of the override methods get invoked.
**THANK YOU**

Comment: Can you check which view controller is being returned by `children.first` in the `UITabBarController` extension?

Comment: That's my problem I can't hit that, that's what I meant when I said "None of the override methods get invoked"

Comment: This is happening to me on iOS 9 only, higher versions call it just fine.

Comment: Yes @Rivera I've noticed that too, guess it is a bug on iOS 9

Comment: I added my answer here, Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801660/299610

Answer (score -2):

Please try this it will help you.
in AppDelegate class `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method write this.

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
```

it may helps you thank you.

Comment: This has been deprecated, that is why I use preferredStatusBarStyle. and this is a global set and I want to be able to set for individual ViewControllers