# How do I change the default status bar color when overriding system UI style in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ios13, ios-darkmode

When I override overrideUserInterfaceStyle to light and dark mode is set to on, on the device, it is not changing the status bar style to .lightcontent.

```
                    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]
                    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
                    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

That is my code for overridng the interfacce style. When I do this the statusbar is staying with dark content.

Answer (score 0):

If your content is inside a `UINavigationController`, you won't get what you expect. You will have to subclass `UINavigationController` to reach into its content and promote that view controller's overridden value.

See this thread for some answers: [preferredStatusBarStyle isn't called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022210/preferredstatusbarstyle-isnt-called/19513714#19513714)