# Printing Date via NSLog with format

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nslog

Is it possible to print an NSDate object via NSLog without also printing the hour, minute, seconds? What I want it to log is this format yyyy-MM-dd, without the hour, minute, seconds.

I already have an NSDateFormatter with yyyy-MM-dd but when I print the NSDate object via NSLog, it still gives me the hour, minute, second.

Is there a way to do this without creating another string from the date object then logging that string?

Comment: You can use an NSDateFormatter to produce any format you want.  The point is, you must format the date into a string, not simply wave the formatter around an NSDate and expect to change the NSDate.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have already formatted my NSDate via NSDateFormatter with the yyyy-MM-dd format. But when I NSLog the NSDate object, it still gives me the hours, minutes, seconds

Comment: `NSDateFormatter` doesn't modify an existing `NSDate` object, nor does it produce a new one. It just offers you the ability to produce an `NSString` of a desired format, from an `NSDate`. So yes, you'll have to format it every time you want to print it to the console, or retain the `NSString` if the date is not changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass nsdate and override the description method to return a formatted string.  Or write a category to do the same and just call the category method in your log statements.

Comment: Yeah, a category would be the way to go, if one wants to do anything at all in this regard.

Comment: It's worth noting that overriding methods using categories is not recommended. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that:  only to add another method that does what he wants

Answer (score 1):

When `NSLog` encounters an objective-c object (via the `%@` token), it calls the method `-[NSObject description]` and prints the resulting string in its place. `NSDate`'s implementation of that method prints out hours, minutes, and seconds. The only way to have it print something differently is to generate a string yourself using `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. So there isn't really any other way to do this without creating my own string.