# Is it OK to override UIViewController methods on a category on UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, overriding, uitableview, objective-c-category

I know you should not override methods in a category that are defined in the class the category is for. But what about overriding inherited methods. Is that OK?

Specifically, UITableViewController inherits methods like viewWillAppear:, viewWillDisappear, viewDidLoad: and so on, from UIViewController.

So, let's say in a category on UITableViewController, we override those methods inherited from UIViewController.

Is it OK?

As far as I can tell, this will only break if Apple in some future version of UIKit decides to override these methods in UITableViewController.

Are there other reasons not to do this?

EDIT:

So the part about overriding methods in categories in the documentation passed under my radar, so thanks for the answer.

I'll have to solve this with subclassing and possibly extensions.

Comment: Are there reasons not to sub-class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding methods in a category is discouraged. See [Overriding methods using categories in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c)

In my opinion it doesn't matter if this means overriding an inherited or class-defined method. Why should it make a difference? Why not subclass?

Comment: The main motivation for using category is that I want to add multiple narrowly defined behaviors to my class. Since multiple inheritance is not an option, I don't see how I can achieve this without categories.