# UILabel with category in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uilabel

I've made simple `UILabel` with custom font. Can I use it in `Storyboard` somehow? Is it even possible?

```
#import "UILabel+WithFont.h"

@implementation UILabel (WithFont)

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    float size = [self.font pointSize];
    self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyFont" size:size];
}

@end
```

Maybe I can switch between `UILabel` and my `UILabel` with *category* in code?

Comment: You better subclass it instead categoryizing.

Comment: Can I use subclass in storyboard?

Comment: Yes. Same as with xib's.

Comment: [Please don't.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/792677).

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks guys, now I know what should I do;)