# Custom font with size classes in iOS

Tags: ios, class, fonts, size, xcode6

I'm trying to add 2 different font sizes for iphone and ipad layouts using size classes. It works cool with a default System font but doesn't work with custom font(I'm using PragmataPro in my project). If I add the second size for wR hR then font looks correctly in interface builder(I even checked xml) but in simulator and on device it becomes System instead of PragmataPro. But if I remove wR hR(or whatever layout I'm using for another size) then font shows correctly. Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166737/custom-font-sizing-in-ios-8-size-classes-not-working-properly-w-custom-fonts

Answer (score 3):

Subclass UILabel and override "layoutSubviews" method like:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
 [super layoutSubviews];
 // Implement font logic depending on screen size
  self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"CustomFont" size:self.font.pointSize];
}
```

Comment: That will work, but I am wondering why I cannot do the same in the xib itself.

Comment: check this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard

Comment: I think u misunderstand the problem here. The problem is not using the custom font in xib/storyboard. The problem is using different sizes of  custom font for different size classes. The single font size doesn't create any problem unless you add different font size for different layouts.

Comment: @RamarajT did you find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link (it is a step-by-step from Apple):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/ChangingtheFontforaSizeClass.html

Comment: This works only for the system fonts, but if you your custom font, this wont work

Answer (score -1):

The 'custom' is there to define one single setting per type class.
If you don't define a 'custom' library with all the variations you want than I don't really think there to be a solution, mainly because by 'custom' you mean ONE SINGLE COMPONENT OF A GIVEN LIST OF CHOICES...