# Make Interface Builder draw IB_DESIGNABLE subviews with the currently selected size class

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, size-classes, ibdesignable

I have a XIB (file's owner: `DesignableView`) that I laid out in Interface Builder in two different size classes:

---

#### DesignableView.xib: Any | Any

[image: Designable View.xib: Any | Any]

---

#### DesignableView.xib: Regular | Any

[image: Designable View.xib: Regular | Any]

---

I want to use this `DesignableView` inside another XIB file. As I am a huge [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) fan I made the view `IB_DESIGNABLE` and added the following code to the file's owner class:

**DesignableView.h**

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface DesignableView : UIView

@end
```

**DesignableView.m**

```
@implementation DesignableView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self loadNib];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self loadNib];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadNib
{
    NSString *nibName = NSStringFromClass(self.class);
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.class];
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:nibName bundle:bundle];
    UIView *view = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0];
    view.frame = self.bounds;
    view.layoutMargins = self.layoutMargins;
    [self addSubview:view];
}

@end
```

All this code does is rendering the view wherever I use it in Interface Builder.

Now I create another XIB file and set its file's owner to `ContainerView`. I add two empty UIViews to it and set their class property to `DesignableView`. Interface Builder updates the views after a few seconds and shows the two `DesignableView`s as laid out in the first XIB - just as expected.

However, it always loads the layout specified in the "Any | Any" size class of `DesignableView` - regardless of `ContainerView`'s size class (see screenshots below).

---

#### ContainerView.xib: Any | Any

[image: Container View.xib: Any | Any]

---

#### ContainerView.xib: Regular | Any

[image: Container View.xib: Regular | Any]

---

(At runtime the `DesignableView` always appears with the correct size class layout.)

**Is there any way to make Interface Builder display IB_DESIGNABLE views in the correct size class?**

*i.e. the wanted behavior is:*

```
while editing ContainerView.xib in Interface Builder

↓

switch size class (e.g. to Regular | Any)

↓

Interface Builder draws subviews with class `DesignableView` 
with the respective size class (Regular | Any)
```

Comment: Great question, looks like there's an open radar about it mentioned here, but it's a year old now :( http://stackoverflow.com/a/33810688/1679697

Comment: Thanks for the link! Good to know it's a problem that Apple is aware of but it's really unsatisfying that it hasn't been resolved yet. :( How can you tell it's a year old? Quinn's answer is from Nov 19 '15, right?

Comment: Oh yes, not a year then- I must have read the question date (Feb '15) as the answer date. Very annoying that it's not sorted even so!