# Increase the font size for different type of iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I want increase font size when iPhone device size get bigger.if there is any want increase font size in autolayout in Xcode.there is option to change only for iPhone and iPad.
Is any option available to change font size for 4s,5SE,iphone6,iphone 6 plus for Xcode or code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make text labels scale the font size with different Apple product screens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644128/how-do-i-make-text-labels-scale-the-font-size-with-different-apple-product-scree)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following code for this, it can change your fonts according to phones screen size.

```
    if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 480 )
    {
        // iPhone 4
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:15.0];
    }
    else if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568 )
    {
        // iPhone 5
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:15.0];            
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width==375)
    {
        // iPhone 6
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:17.0];
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width==414)
    {
        // iPhone 6+
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:17.0];
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width==812)
    {
        // iPhone X
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:17.0];
    }
    else if([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width==768)
    {
        // iPad
        _title.font=[UIFont regularfont:14.0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use flexible font size , first you should have to make a flexible label which is resize with different device size. Once you set that you can use below method to set font as per label size.

```
yourLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```