# view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass returning undefined (0) in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using a UITextView inside a UIPageViewController, and I want to determine the font size based on the size class of the device.

The first slide of the page view is loaded in ViewDidLoad like so (`viewControllerAtIndex(0)`):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Some unrelated code here

    // Page View Controller for Questions Slider
    questionPageVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("QuestionPageView") as? UIPageViewController
    questionPageVC!.dataSource = self;
    questionPageVC!.delegate = self;

    let startingViewController : QuestionContentViewController = viewControllerAtIndex(0) as QuestionContentViewController
    var viewControllers = [startingViewController]

    questionPageVC!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let sliderHeight = view.frame.size.height * 0.5
    questionPageVC!.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 70,
     view.frame.size.width-40, sliderHeight)

    addChildViewController(questionPageVC!)
    view.addSubview(questionPageVC!.view!)
    questionPageVC?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    var pageControl : UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearance()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    // Some more code here
}
```

And then, in viewControllerAtIndex:

```
private func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> QuestionContentViewController {
    var pcvc : QuestionContentViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("QuestionContentView") as! QuestionContentViewController

    var fontSize = ""

    if (view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == UIUserInterfaceSizeClass.Compact) {
        fontSize = "20"
    } else {
        fontSize = "28"
    }

    pcvc.questionString = TextFormatter(string: fontSize + questionsArray[index]).formattedString
    pcvc.questionIndex = index

    return pcvc

}
```

The problem is that the very first slide, which was called in viewDidLoad, always uses the font size in the "else" clause.

If I print `view.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass`, for that first slide, I get 0 (`UIUserInterfaceSizeClassUnspecified`), for subsequent slides, I get the correct size.

I tried moving the whole thing to "viewWillAppear", and then weird things happen to the UIPageViewController (an extra slide with the wrong size text behind the other slides)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem is that `viewDidLoad` is too soon to be asking about a view's trait collection. This is because the trait collection of a view is a feature acquired from the view hierarchy, the environment in which it finds itself. But in `viewDidLoad`, the view has *no* environment: it is not *in* in the view hierarchy yet. It has *loaded*, meaning that it exists: the view controller now *has* a view. But it has not been put into the interface yet, and it will not be put into the interface until `viewDidAppear:`, which comes later in the sequence of events.

However, the view *controller* also has a trait collection, and it *does* have an environment: by the time `viewDidLoad` is called, the view controller is part of the view controller hierarchy. Therefore the simplest (and correct) solution is to ask for the `traitCollection` of `self`, not of `view`. Just say `self.traitCollection` where you now have `view.traitCollection`, and all will be well.

(Your solution, asking the screen for its trait collection, may *happen* to work, but it is not reliable and is not the correct approach. This is because it is possible for the parent view controller to alter the trait collection of its child, and if you bypass the correct approach and ask the screen, directly, you will fail to get the correct trait collection.)

Comment: Thanks @matt. I saw in the documentation that, as you say, you controllers also have traitCollection, I don't know why I didn't try that.

Comment: When referencing the view controller's trait collection I still get 0 clear up until traitCollectionDidChange gets called. Only after that do I have the actual size classes. This is inside a view controller that is part of a page view controller.

Comment: @JeremyHicks That's right, the view controller has no trait collection until it has an environment, i.e. it is part of the view controller hierarchy. With a page view controller, it isn't part of the view controller hierarchy until you have handed it to the page view controller.

Comment: @matt I think I see what you mean. With a page view controller all the viewDid* methods have already been called before my view controller is part of the view controller hierarchy. So, how can I fix this issue for that first view controller? Like coopersita, this is only happening for me with that first view controller. The rest are fine.

Comment: I figured it out. As you suggested, I had to add the page view controller to the view controller hierarchy BEFORE I added my view controller to the page view controller. Thanks!

Comment: This answer sounds like it's possible to do self.traitCollection from a VC's viewDidLoad, while in fact that is too early.

Comment: To access the trait collection as early as possible (to base my layout on it), ensure you're accessing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` to ensure the layout's complete.

Comment: The answer states that "by the time viewDidLoad is called, the view controller is part of the view controller hierarchy", but this is not always correct. For example, calling `loadViewIfNeeded` or accessing any property of a UIViewControllers `view` causes the system to call `viewDidLoad`, even if the ViewController has not been added to the view hierachy. The traitCollection is not fully setup in that case.

Comment: Seems like this is true no longer. In Xcode 11 Beta I am getting correct `traitCollection` right after view controller init without placing it to any hierarchy. And even for it's root view..

Comment: Correct, they now guess early so you have a value. But on the other hand you lose the Changed event.

Comment: I'm having some issues on some iPads with iOS < 13 in which sometimes `traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` was `.unspecified` even though I'm checking it in `viewWillAppear`. Moving the check to `viewDidAppear` fixed my problem.

Comment: @juancazalla Yes, I can believe that. This behavior changed in iOS 13 which is why you didn't see the issue except on iOS 12 and earlier. I'll adjust my answer to mention `viewDidAppear`. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

I found that if I use the main screen's traitCollection, instead of the current view, I get the correct  size class:

```
if (UIScreen.main.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .compact) {
    fontSize = "20"
} else {
    fontSize = "28"
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I was wondering how to get this value sooner. Not just in the view lifecycle but in the App lifecycle. I can get the appropriate information in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. This is great because it lets me make decisions about what UI to use when I'm not using storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

You will be better off moving that code to the viewWillAppear method, as in the viewDidLoad the ViewController's view has not been added to the hierarchy yet, and you might get an empty trait collection.

Comment: This worked for me. When presenting a VC modally, and doing `self.traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` inside of viewDidLoad resulted in 0 instead of an expected portrait value (2).

Comment: I'm having some issues on some iPads with iOS < 13 in which sometimes `traitCollection.verticalSizeClass` was `.unspecified` even though I'm checking it in `viewWillAppear`. Moving the check to `viewDidAppear` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I needed my view to know about the horizontalSizeClass so accessing the UIScreen traitCollection was tempting but not encouraged, so I had something like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    print("\(self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass.rawValue)")

    switch self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
    case .regular, .unspecified:
        fontSize = 28

    case .compact:
        fontSize = 20
    }
}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    print("\(self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass.rawValue)")

    guard let previousTraitCollection = previousTraitCollection else { return }

    if self.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass != previousTraitCollection.horizontalSizeClass {
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it a try on my next project.

Comment: @mazen-kasser Why you put .compact and .unspecified together ? What about (anyH compV) in Storyboard ?)

Comment: @iTux in this case checking against the `horizontalSizeClass`, you can also check the `verticalSizeClass`

Answer (score 0):

I took a hint from this [Apple Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1890/_index.html) and used `viewWillLayoutSubviews` instead of `viewDidLoad`/`viewWillAppear`.