# Subclass UITextField to override font when using size classes with custom font

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, subclass

I'm trying to subclass UITextField in order to set the font correctly as per the answer to this question: [Custom Font Sizing in XCode6 Size Classes Not Working Properly w/ Custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166737/custom-font-sizing-in-xcode6-size-classes-not-working-properly-w-custom-fonts)

I have a text field with a custom font and when I use size classes I lose ALL custom fonts in my app. They default to system.

I've tried to do the same thing for the UITextField as the answer to that question suggested for UILabel, but with no joy.

My Subclass:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomUITextField: UITextField {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.font = UIFont(name: "Score Board", size: self.font!.pointSize)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this turned out to be a *really* **weird** bug. It *does* work provided there is an element on your storyboard that is not set to `System` font, but is set to your **custom** font.

My fix was to put in an invisible label that was **not** using my subclass but set to the custom font in `Interface Builder`. Now all my other fonts, which are set to `System` in `Interface Builder`, are overridden in my custom classes correctly.

Thanks, Apple!