# How to set font sizes for different iPhone sizes?

Tags: ios

I know there are a variety of ways to do make different font sizes for different sized devices, but unsure how to go about implementing them and the pros/cons of each. Would you mind helping me out?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO].Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I implemented it. Made a class function in appconfig to get the scaling factor for iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus

```
+(NSInteger)scalingFactor {
    NSInteger scalingFactor = 0;
    if (IS_IPHONE6) {
        scalingFactor = 1.0;
    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE6_PLUS){
        scalingFactor = 2.0;
    }

    return scalingFactor;
}
```

Then used the scaling factor wherever I need it.

```
+ (UIFont *) fontForSearchCancelButtonTitle{
    return [UIFont proximaNovaLightFontOfSize:17.0f + [AppConfig scalingFactor]];
}
```

And for getting iphone 6 and iphone 6 plus:

```
#define IS_IPHONE6 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-667)?NO:YES)
#define IS_IPHONE6_PLUS (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-736)?NO:YES)
```

Comment: Thank you @Kunal..its working awesome..but i want to set with in attribute inspector...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nszta.png

check the above image.we are using minimum font scale its working fine in system font but custom font does not working...

Comment: yup not working for me as well. You might want to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166737/custom-font-sizing-in-xcode6-size-classes-not-working-properly-w-custom-fonts