# Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have Got this waning while using this code

```
-(void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // [[UIColor ] setFill];

    BOOL currentdevice=[[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"];
    if(currentdevice)
    {
        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15] }];

    }
    else
    {

        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:20]}];
    }

}
```

To Stop the warning message i am using this code

```
@implementation UITextField (placeholder)
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-protocol-method-implementation"

// do your override
-(void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // [[UIColor ] setFill];

    BOOL currentdevice=[[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"];
    if(currentdevice)
    {

        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15] }];

    }
    else
    {

        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:20]}];
    }

}


#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

is there any problem if i use like this ..

or please give me exact way to override the method thanks....

Comment: Technically, it will work.  It's better to avoid this, however, as technically the choice of which implementation will be used is not defined.

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/1186243

Comment: is there any way to do this in proper way @Avi

Comment: It would be better to subclass.

Comment: can you explain it briefly how to do that @Avi :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For non UI customization its better to subclass.** Assign TextField Class as CustomTextField where ever you require drawPlaceholderInRect as per your implementation

**//  CustomTextField.h**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface CustomTextField : UITextField

    @end
```

**//CustomTextField.m**

```
#import "CustomTextField.h"

@implementation CustomTextField

- (void)drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {

    BOOL currentdevice=[[UIDevice currentDevice].model hasPrefix:@"iPhone"];
    if(currentdevice){
        NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],
                                         NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:15.0]
                                         };

        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrDictionary];

    }
    else{

        NSDictionary *attrDictionary = @{
                                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor],
                                         NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:20.0]
                                         };

        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attrDictionary];
    }

  }
@end
```

[image: Set Class as custom class]

Comment: but its didn't change the placeholder colour what to do bro @Muhammad

Comment: are you subclassing TextField with CustomTextField?

Comment: are you setting CustomTextField as Class of your TextField in Storyboard or xib ?

Comment: One more thing have you set any placeholder text in Interface  builder?

Comment: no i didn't set this custom class to to my textfield bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97985/discussion-between-kishore-kumar-and-muhammad).

Comment: check edited Answer and image for subclassing textField