# Intercept when a user navigates to a new view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am working on an app where I will need to figure out if a user moved to a new viewcontoller, this would include if a new view controller is presented or when you come back to an earlier view controller, I have tried implementing this with a UIViewController category and intercepting user navigating to a page by overriding  "viewDidAppear", but I don't want to use a category to do this as there is a high impact on every view controller, is there any way I would be able to do this?

Example: So we are working on sharing ur app screen to a customer service rep, a rep has his own rules for example there are 2 pages in an application, when customer is sharing his app screen and is on page 1, I will check the rules and figure out whether the rep should see the page and when customer navigates to page 2 and rep doesn't have permission to view this, I will pause the screen sharing because I realized page 2 is not in rep's permissions and now when I go back to page 1, I will need to check permissions again and show the page to rep(essentially resuming the screen sharing)

Comment: You should *NEVER* use categories to override existing methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272451/overriding-methods-using-categories-in-objective-c

Comment: @vikingosegundo thats exactly why I do not want to do that and trying to find a different solution, so honestly speaking I need to be able to intercept when topViewcontroller changes? I mean the visible view controller changing is what needs to be intercepted

Comment: why dont you use a common UIViewController subclass that override viewDidAppear? another way that comes to my mind would be Aspect Oriented Programming. Several libraries for objective-c do exist.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I can't use UIViewController subclass because I already have about 200 Viewcontrollers in the app and I will have to go manually in to each class and add everything to be inherited from the base class

Comment: I cannot imaging any app that needs 200 view controllers. I'd say that is a problem you should fix first.

Comment: its a banking application which also works on claims, loans, insurance and a lot of other stuff, there is a team of over 80 people working on this application and mostly our customers bank using the app or the website, so it has a lot of things

Comment: Sounds like this team of 80 needs a software architect. let me guess: your view controllers are also huge and do implement delegates and datasources.

Comment: no we try to stay away from that :D, its not a design honestly, its just a huge app, we try to have everything accessible through the app because our customers are mostly outside the country and can't visit a physical office location

Comment: still: no need for 200 view controllers. read up [SOLID priciples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)), [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). I am sure that you have a lot of copy and pasted code and codes that could be reduced if properly parameterised. This is important as duplicated codes mean duplicated errors — something you dont want in a banking application.

Comment: btw: what is the name of the app?

Comment: there might be duplicated code in there, but definitely not the reason why we have so many view controllers, I think there are about 10-15 architects working on the design since 2008, the number of view controllers thing is definitely not avoidable for our app, different divisions in our company need different designs, u can basically think of us as though we have around 15 different companies within our company, so is there a way to do it without using inheritance? worse comes to worse I can always base class i and have every other base view controller inherit from mine

Comment: If inheritance in an OO language isn't an option, something is very very wrong. Besides that I named another approach. AOP. ask google "objective-c AOP" and you will find a lot.

Comment: or bad architects :p

Comment: well, that's the same.

Comment: @vikingosegundo so I used CADisplayLink, to see if the topViewcontroller is changing, I seemed to achieve what I needed. Do you think thats a good idea?

Comment: can you post it ans an answer, with code?

Comment: @vikingosegundo added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by the following, I have a "CADisplayLink" as the following

I create properties

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *topViewController;//This will essentially be the visible view controller at any time
@property(nonatomic, strong) CADisplayLink *displayLink;
```

then I instantiate the "displayLink"

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(checkTopViewController)];
self.displayLink.frameInterval = 2;//I want the refresh rate to be slower than with the UI refresh rate
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void)checkTopViewController{
    UIViewController *vc = [self findBestViewController:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController];
    if (self.topViewController != vc) {
        self.topViewController = vc;
        //Top visible view controller changed
    }
}

-(UIViewController*) findBestViewController:(UIViewController*)vc {

    if (vc.presentedViewController) {

        // Return presented view controller
        return [UIViewController findBestViewController:vc.presentedViewController];

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {

        // Return right hand side
        UISplitViewController* svc = (UISplitViewController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.viewControllers.lastObject];
        else
            return vc;

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

        // Return top view
        UINavigationController* svc = (UINavigationController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.topViewController];
        else
            return vc;

    } else if ([vc isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {

        // Return visible view
        UITabBarController* svc = (UITabBarController*) vc;
        if (svc.viewControllers.count > 0)
            return [UIViewController findBestViewController:svc.selectedViewController];
        else
            return vc;

    } else {

        // Unknown view controller type, return last child view controller
        return vc;

    }

}
```

Comment: this certainly works, but it seems to me to be a "polling" approach, where 30 times a second this code is run. Not ver performant. Better would be "pushing" approach, where the view controller newly comping to front informs about this. The solutions I suggested would be "pushing" approaches. Still up vote for an unconventional solution,

Comment: so safe bet would always be just make sure that everything in our application is subclassed from a base class correct?

Comment: as I said before: that would be the normal approach. Other approaches: AOP, or — similar to AOP — as long as you stay in the objective-c world: method-swizzling.

Comment: I swizzled, viewDidAppear before this and my code was rejected by our code review team

Comment: So there are some sane people in your team.

Comment: yeah there are some