# UIStatusBarStyleLightContent for MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uistatusbar

Can you please suggest me, what is the proper way to setup the style of statusbar for `MFMailComposeViewController` in iOS >= 9.0?
I know, that `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];` is deprecated and I can't use it.
I know that the possible solution is adding category like this:

```
#import "MFMailComposeViewController+StatusBarStyle.h"
@implementation MFMailComposeViewController (StatusBarStyle)
#pragma mark - Status bar management
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle {
    return nil;
}
@end
```

But in this case I should enable `View controller-based status bar appearance` option and implement `- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle` in the all ViewContollers that exist in my app (and I have a lot of them).
So, is there another solution?

Comment: it is wrong to add a category when you want to override something, so it is not a solution at all

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272612/907692 for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I created my own `CommonNavigationViewController`, added these two methods:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (UIViewController *)childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle {
    return nil;
}
```

And changed the class of Root Navigation Controller in Storyboard to this one.
It helps and now the all VCs that appears in Navigation Controller's stack have the Light Status bar. But anyway, I don't like this solution :(

Answer (score -1):

```
(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

Add this to `yourviewcontroller.m` file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks