# Load a Saved Image in iOS

Tags: ios, filesystems

What I am doing is to save an image loaded from any source,(camera / library) and saving it to filesystem in iOS.
What I m stuck is at how I can use that save image..
I m using the following code. Its working it is creating a Test.jpg in Documents Folder. 
But Really have no idea how to access this Test.jpg.

```
NSString  *jpgPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Test.jpg"];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedImage.image, 1.0) writeToFile:jpgPath atomically:YES];
NSError *error;
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Test.jpg"];`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use this method:

`let testImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)`

`imageNamed` looks for an image with the specified name in the application’s main bundle.

Comment: If you want to cache image from Documents directory then see [Any way to get a Cached UIImage from my 'Documents' directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338727/any-way-to-get-a-cached-uiimage-from-my-documents-directory)

Answer (score 3):

In Swift:

```
let testImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```