# How to access image object from file system path in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, uiimage, phonegap-plugins

I have a Phonegap app that saves images the user takes from the camera to the device file system. I want to be able to access this image object in iOS/Objective C but can't seem to figure out how and don't see any explanations that solve the issue.

I'm able to see the path to the file (something like "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/XXXX-XX-XXXXX/Documents/tempImg.jpg"), and can display this image properly setting HTML img src to this location, but when I try to access the image object in native code something is not working. I've tried using the code below

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgName]
```

where imgName is the path in quotes above, but it does not work. Should I be doing something else?

I've checked all the Stack Overflow answers I could find like the link below, but nothing's working

[Load a Saved Image in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8277640/load-a-saved-image-in-ios)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Your "path" in quotes is not a path. It's a file URL. Not the same thing. If you have an `NSURL`, use the `path` method to get a file system path from the file URL.

Comment: Information on the file system on iOS https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: Just consider removing "file:///" from your image URL... and use it with your imageWithContentsOfFile function. @manihiki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filepath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"tempImg.jpg"];
UIImage myImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filepath];
```